# Permission to run specific programs

Tags: windows-xp

I have a XP Service pack 2 installed on my homne machine. I have admin access to this machine but I want to run most of my programs as non admin user. 
How can I do this?
I know I need to create a new account, what rights should I grant that account?
How do I make sure apps like Adobe photoshop, Itunes are accessible to this newly created account

Comment: You seem to have got two accounts (the id of the one used for the question is 10051, while the answer is from account id 10104) - you can tell because the name isn't highlighted on the answer. Contact team@stackoverflow.com about getting the accounts merged.

Answer (score 2):

[DropMyRights](http://download.cnet.com/DropMyRights/3000-2144_4-10722877.html), absolutely essential when using an account with with admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DropMyRights would be a good choice. Better still, you can create a limited user account and then give admin privilege to only those programs that require admin privileges. However, changing application privilege is only supported in Windows XP Pro, it's not present in Windows XP Home. Here's an article about limited user accounts in Windows:
http://blog.washingtonpost.com/securityfix/2006/05/the_importance_of_the_limited.html